# insert string at the beginning of each line in text file after certain header strings

Tags: command-line

I want to insert a string at the beginning of each line after match string

original file:-

```
header1
blue green yellow
bird cat dog

header2
reg edit last
arrow edit blue
```

Target file:-

```
header1
header1 blue green yellow
header1 bird cat dog

header2
header2 reg edit last
header2 arrow edit blue
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your problem/question regarding this task?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your original and target file, otherwise we cannot see what you want to do. Use the (?) for formatting help if needed.

Answer (score 1):

AWK allows you to match a pattern and save it for later use.

```
awk 'match($1,/(header[0-9]+)/,m) { v = m[1]; print $0; next } { (NF>0 && v) ? $0 = sprintf("%s %s", v, $0) : v = "" }1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `awk` command for that

```
awk 'BEGIN{header=""} {if(length($0)==0)header=""; if(NF==1){header=$0; print header;} else print header " " $0}' srcfile > tgtfile
```

- `if(length($0)==0)header=""` will check if the `srcfile` contains a blankline, if yes, the text to be prefixed is set to blank string.
- `if(NF==1){header=$0; print header;}` is used to find the string to be prefixed to each line and it is printed.
- `print header " " $0` is used to find the line to which the string is to be prefixed. once such lines are found, the string is prefixed and printed.

***Note: `srcfile` is your input file and `tgtfile` is the output file. Change the names as desired.***